# Python Библиотека shutil есть ли там работа с passwod?

Tags: python, shutil

У меня есть папка где лежат архивы разных расширений, этот модуль хорошо подходит для извлечения под разными расширениями архив типо zip, rar, tur и т.д. но у некоторых архивов стоят пароли. (Я знаю что у zipfile есть такой параметр для извлечение архивов с паролями, но он работает только с .zip)
И хотелось бы узнать есть у shutil такой параметр или функция для извлечения запороленных архивов?

Comment: Читаю документацию, вроде как `shutil` не предоставляет возможности работы с запаролеными архивами...